# precede versus take precedence of

Tags: expressions, phrasal-verbs

I would like to describe the relationship between two start dates. I have been repeatedly using "start date of A precede the start date of B."

I am wondering if an alternative expression "start date of A takes precedence of the start date of B" can be used to say the A happens before B.

I've looked up the dictionary and it seems to me that A would have to be more important than B if this expression is to be used. However, A and B are equally important in my case.

Comment: I agree with your dictionary. To me, "A takes precedence over [I've never heard "of" in this context] B" means that, in case of a conflict between A and B, A wins.

Answer (score 2):

No. Precede means that one thing comes before another in order, space, or time. So one might say that the marching band precedes the horse guards in a parade, if the band is placed ahead of the horses. One might also say that in the English alphabet L precedes M, and that sunrise precedes noon.

By contrast, "precedence" usually refers (as your dictionary research shows) to a  difference of importance or priority in the relationship between two things. The meeting you have this afternoon with another party may take precedence over everything else you have to do today, because it is important, but it may be preceded by breakfast, lunch and a swim in the morning.